# Load Data from Database Without Blinking Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Am loading data from database to a table in html with angualar js. am also using interval so as to make the table reload every 10 seconds to get new data that has just been inputed by other users.

**Problem:**
The table blinks every time it reloads. making the page look funny like it has a glitch.

**What am looking for:**
Is there a way i can make the new data just slide in from the top of the table and become number one while the rest re adjust underneath it And become number two, three and so on. i was made to believe Angular Js is magical reason why i opted for it instead of using my usual AJAX

**Angular Code**

```
 var supDetails = angular.module("supDetails", ['datatables']);

     supDetails.controller('supportController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
          $scope.names = [];
$scope.isFirst = true;
$scope.loadData = function() {    
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'anfil.php?ins=sup'

    }).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log('loading..');
        $scope.names = data;

       if(!$scope.isFirst){
          angular.forEach(data,function(key,val){
            $scope.names[key] = data[key];
          });
        }            
        $scope.isFirst = false;
    });

};

         $scope.loadData();

// Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.

   $interval(function () {
         $scope.loadData();
}, 10000);

    });
```

**My HTML**

```
 <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-md-9" ng-app = "supDetails" ng-controller="supportController">
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title">Messages</h3>
          <!-- /.box-tools -->
           <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <div class="has-feedback">
             <button type="button" ng-click="loadData()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body no-padding">

          <div class="mailbox-messages">
            <table datatable="ng" class="table table-hover table-striped">
             <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Stat</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Problem</th>
              <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td class="mailbox-star"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-blue"></i></a></td>
                <td class="mailbox-name"><a href="read-mail.html">{{x.user_id}}</a></td>
                <td class="mailbox-subject"><b>{{x.ticket_title}}</b> - {{x.subject}}
                </td>
                <td class="mailbox-date">{{x.ticket_open_date}}</td>
              </tr>

              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                 <tr>
              <th>Stat</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Problem</th>
              <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
            <!-- /.table -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.mail-box-messages -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
      <!-- /. box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
```

Comment: Thanks for making my day, I hardly laugh when browsing SO. "i was made to believe Angular Js is magical". Yeah, surprisingly, it is not magic. You can ask the wizards at google who wrote it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its your css problem which doesn't have a minimum height as you can see in this snippet its not blinking..

If you still want data to appear slide from up to down, You can uncomment the code in the answer, in this way it will remove row one by one from the table and replace it with the new one.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http,$interval) {

    $scope.people = [];
    $scope.isFirst = true;
    $scope.loadPeople = function() {    
        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

        }).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log('loading..');
            $scope.people = data;
            
           /* if(!$scope.isFirst){
              angular.forEach(data,function(val,key){
                $scope.people[key] = data[key];
              });
            }            
            $scope.isFirst = false;*/
        });

    };
    
    $scope.loadPeople();
      $interval(function () {
              $scope.loadPeople();
    }, 10000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
  
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>UserNmae</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.username}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you still want data to appear slide from up to down you can uncomment the code in the answer in this way it will remove one by on row from the table and replace it with the new one.

Comment: my table is still blinking. like it the entire table loads again

Comment: try this same example but instead of the table to have just ten users. let it be increasing to 11,12 and so on. let me see if it will bling

Comment: @nsikak you have to share some code so that we could find out wats the problem.

Comment: Have updated my code to show my HTML and also your your code i added. am also using bootstrap. also an my console it doesn't blink but blinks on the table

Comment: @nsikak remove the datatable="ng" and see if its still blinking

Comment: Lol it as stopped, so how do i make this work with angular datatable

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to solve your problems:

1) Write algorithm, that load your data then compare it with existing data. If there any diffs you, should add just new records to your table.

2) Use WebSockets, they will give you ability to get from server only new records in real-time.